# pow(1,0) returns 0?

Tags: c, printf, pow, ansi-c

Why does this:

```
printf("%d\n", pow(1,0)); /* outputs 0 */
```

returns `0`? I expected it to return `1`.

Comment: I believe there is nothing specific to C89 here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`pow()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow) returns a `double` type. You need to use `%f` format specifier to print a `double`.

Using inappropriate format specifier for the supplied argument type causes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Check chapter §7.21.6.1 of the C standard N1570 (`C11`). (Yes, this has nothing specific to `C89`, IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

You need to type cast the result to int as pow() returns double.

```
printf("%d\n",(int) pow(1,0));
```

This give your desired output 1

note:`pow(a,b)` gives correct result when both a and b are `integers` as in your case.But you need to `add 0.5` to the result when dealing with `fractions` so that the result gets **rounded off to nearest integer**.

```
printf("%d\n",(int) (pow(2.1,0.9)))// will return 1. 

printf("%d\n",(int) (pow(2.1,0.9)+0.5));//will return 2.
```

Hope it helps you.